# Bitmap scaling to fit different screen size/density

Tags: android, screen-resolution

I do not really understand all those things about pixel density and device independant pixels and I want to know if I should worry about this.

More specifically, here is how my application work right now:

- For the “layout screens”, I’m using RelativeLayout or LinearLayout and I never use pixels or dp, so I guess that this will look good on every device
- For the main game screen, there is only a SurfaceView on the screen. With the values given by `onSurfaceCreated()` (pixels or dp? I don’t know), I compute the size and position of every element of the game, then I load the Bitmaps (with `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()` and then `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`) and put them on the screen with `drawBitmap()`

I tested on my phone (480 × 800 hdpi) and on the emulator (240 × 320 mdpi), and both looks good.

My questions are:

- Is this the right thing to do? I do not understand how (and why) I could use the fact that some devices are hdpi and others are mdpi.
- Should I provide different bitmaps for different screen densities, and why? (right now I have everything in `res/drawable-hdpi`)
- What size should my .png have? Can I create them much bigger (2 ×) than their expected size, in order to be sure that this will not look blur or aliased?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My knowledge about this is limited, as i never developed games.. as i supposed you are doing.

> Is this the right thing to do? I do
>   not understand how (and why) I could
>   use the fact that some devices are
>   hdpi and others are mdpi.

With this information you can load different images automatically. You can you the directories:

drawable-hdpi
drawables-mdpi
...

> Should I provide different bitmaps for
>   different screen densities, and why?
>   (right now I have everything in
>   res/drawable-hdpi)

If you have all in hdpi then the images will be shrinked i think, to be smaller due to the lack of specific images o that scale. Providing the images will give you more control over the final product and it will spend less processing.

> What size should my .png have? Can I
>   create them much bigger (2 ×) than
>   their expected size, in order to be
>   sure that this will not look blur or
>   aliased?

I think they can be exactly the size needed. But as i said above.. not much experience.